# Indexing only specific domains with Solr and Nutch

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I want to crawl a website with Nutch and the Index it with Solr.

I have a website which have the following structure:

Homepage: `example.com`

Documents I want to index: `subdomain.example.com/{some_number}.html`

To "discover" all these documents I start from `example.com/discover` which has a list of many documents that I want.

So what I have now is:

In my `regex-urlfilter.txt` I set to crawl only documents from example.com and this works perfectly

I index with Solr and everything works well. I use the following command:

`./$nutch/bin/crawl -i -s $nutch/urls/ $nutch/ 5`

What I want now is to ONLY index the documents that are in the format: `subdomain.example.com/{some_number}.html`, ignoring everything else (i.e. I don't want to index `example.com/discover`)

I guess this is done by changing some configuration in Solr, since it's the indexing part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the configuration could be done on the Nutch side. Filtering the documents before they're sent to Solr.

If you only want to "index" (meaning that you want to fetch&parse all the links, but store only on Solr the ones that match the regex) you can use the [index-jexl-filter](https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/index-jexl-filter). With this plugin, you can write a small [JEXL script](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html) to check if the URL of a document matches your regex and if it does it will be sent to Solr.

The script could be something like (configured on your `nutch-site.xml` file):

```
url =~ "^https?:\/\/[a-z]+\.example.com\/(\d+).html"
```

- `url` is a default primitive available on the JEXL context. You can find more info about this on https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/conf/nutch-default.xml#L1755-L1771

If by "index" you really meant to only crawl the URLs that match your regex (if it doesn't match it will not be fetched nor parsed) then you can use the same `regex-urlfilter.txt` to define the desired format. Keep in mind that with this approach you would need to run the crawl again.

Comment: Thanks for answering! By indexing I meant storing in Solr, so the jexl filter should do the trick. I'm totally new to Nutch and Solr so I'm not understanding well. In my Nutch configuration file I add the `index.jexl.filter` propriety, and in `value` I should put the url like you said, `url=~ ....`? I tried like this by crawling again as well but unwanted documents are indexed anyway.

Comment: You also need to enable the `index-jexl-filter` plugin. For doing this you need to add it to the `value` of `plugin.includes`. For instance you can just add it to the end.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works as I wanted. Meanwhile I found also another solution which is a little bit worse. Instead of crawling and indexing immediately (-i option) I only crawled, then before indexing (using the -filter options), I changed the regex-urlfilter.txt with the Regex to match only the documents I wanted to be indexed.

Comment: Yep, that should work as well. Nice that you found another option. Usually, a deal with continuous running crawls and I jumped directly to the plugin system 